# 64-bit supports Non-ARC?

Tags: objective-c, arm64

I am having a problem on building/archiving my armv7 and armv7s project non-ARC. I need to support the 64-bit on my project so I added arm64 on valid architectures, once I've added the arm64 on the valid architectures the project won't build and archive.

Comment: What errors it gives?

Comment: The problem is there is no error return